# Binding a Point2D to two separate textBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, point

I have a Point2D struct of doubles ( with x and y members). I want to bind an instance of Point2D to two separate TextBoxes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why using struct? Write a class

```
public class Point2D : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double _x;
    private double _y;    

    public double X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            _y = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }    
}
```

The Property in your DataContext

```
public Point2D MyPoint2D { get; set; }
```

And the Binding in XAML

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxValueX" Text="{Binding MyPoint2D.X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Name="TextBoxValueY" Text="{Binding MyPoint2D.Y, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 Also, since you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, you should also add Text="{Binding MyPoint2D.X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}", as well as for Y.